# What is the start current for an AC induction motor with a nominal voltage and current of 72V- 65A?

Tags: high-voltage, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, induction-motor, high-current

I have an induction motor with the specification of 72V rated voltage and 65A of rated curent.

I have power supply with 72V and 100 A of current. Can I use it to move the motor?  The peak curent of the motor is 230A.

Comment: [this power supply (Voltage =72 V and 105 A)\[works\]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/635515/what-is-the-start-current-for-an-ac-induction-motor-with-a-nominal-voltage-and-c#comment1682779_635532), too, sounds a DC power supply. I don't think tag [tag:induction-motor] or, at that, the title of this question is appropriate. (Else, it was a *drive* as in *VFD*, and tag [tag:brushless-dc-motor] doesn't pertain.)

Answer (score 1):

How is that 100A supply controlled? What happens if you draw more than 100A?

What will happen when you first try to power the motor from a standstill is that the windings will be short circuited, so the current draw will be a simple I(max) = V/R, (V is voltage across it, R is resistance of the windings). This is your real peak current.

The 230A peak either means the windings are 0.3Ω (based on R=V/I) or that’s the peak current load. I’d check which it is by measuring the resistance of the windings with a simple meter.

Without any intelligent control, this motor could stall or be too heavily loaded, and start drawing a lot more current, potentially up to 230A or stall current (which ever is higher) and that would then cause the power supply to fail (or go into what every over current mode it has).

So, to answer you question: yes you can, but not with any load on the motor and with a slow gentle start up process.

Alternatively: yes, with a good motor controller, but you can’t get close to full performance out of it due to the power supply limitations.

Alternatively: No, 100A supply is less than 230A peak demand.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reaction,
i tried with this power supply (Voltage =72v and 105 A ) and its works. as you say i tried with slow gentle start up process, the induction motor work perfectly

Comment: @HoussemOuni - Hi, You originally used the box at the bottom of the screen labeled "Your Answer", but your post was not an *answer* so it was deleted & converted into a comment, as I *think* you meant to respond to this answer. Stack Exchange rules differ from typical "linear" forums. You would only use that entry box at the bottom of the screen, if you are writing the full and final answer to your own question. Please read the [tour] & [help] ASAP to see the main site rules, so you can learn about them to help you avoid breaking the site rules again. Thanks.